# Limpar uma datagridview em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tentei tudo isso já e nada serviu. Todos estão excluindo as linhas e coluna. O que eu preciso é limpar o conteúdo escrito nelas.

```
datagridview.datasource=null;
datagridview.resetbindings();
datagridview.Rows.Clear()
DataGridView1.DataSource=null; //Remover a datasource
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); //Remover as colunas
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();    //Remover as linhas
DataGridView1.Refresh();    //Para a grid se actualizar
```

Comment: Qual é o Tipo do objeto que estava no DataSource ?

Comment: BindingSource, uma tabela.

Comment: Com DataSource, componente, acontece isso mesmo, é preferível usar código que é bem mais prático. Um Dica!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá galera resolvi meu problema assim:
Limpar um dataDrid C#

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

Depois é só fazer:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Coluna", "Coluna");//Acrescenta colunas
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Coluna2", "Coluna2");//Acrescenta colunas
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A", "B");//Acrescenta Linhas
```

Comment: Se o conteúdo vem do banco de dados, você está criando uma estrutura que vai exigir manutenção em dois locais, dada qualquer modificação na tabela.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa percorrer as Rows e limpar cada célula da seguinte forma:

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Value = ""; // ou qualquer outro valor que signifique 'limpar' no seu contexto
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentei assim também mas as linhas ficam limpas e não somem, por exemplo, tenho tenho um,datagrid com 10 linhas, o código acima limpa o conteúdo porem fica as 10 linhas. Há outra forma de fazer sumir as linhas sem sumir as colunas?

Answer (score 2):

A principio as outras formas descritas acima nao deram certo aqui, então...

Desta forma retira todas as linhas valores etc, (padrao cinza).

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].DataGridView.Columns.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //LIMPAR GRID
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que fazem essas linhas?

Comment: O código parece identifico ao da pergunta, você mudou apenas a letra maiúscula para minuscula, não entendo como isto resolve o problema. Poderia explicar?

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente eu uso o DataSet (Ds) como DataSource no DataGridView (DGV) e quando quero limpar a grade eu uso o

```
DGV.DataSouce= Ds;
Ds.Clear(); //Retira os valores da tabela mantendo os campos
```

Assim consigo tanto limpar o DGV como atualizar ele. Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

O comando abaixa limpa as linhas exceto o header do grid

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control ctrControl in parent.Controls)
{
if (object.ReferenceEquals(ctrControl.GetType(), typeof(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)))
                    ((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)ctrControl).Rows.Clear();
}
```

fiz assim e vai limpar qualquer form que passar como parâmetro